# Learning Rate Decay (Confusion)

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks, deep-learning, optimization

I want to decay my learning rate by some factor, say factor of 5, after 7 iterations.

Suppose that my initial learning rate is 0.06.

I really don't understand how this works. Some people on the web say that after 7 iterations it should be 5 times smaller. Other people say it should be 5% smaller than the initial value.

This is very confusing. What is correct and what is not?

Comment: It's safe to say that successful application of neural networks is made up of a lot of "black magic"; namely, you'll encounter a lot of general rule of thumbs, yet very little theory backing up what works well and what doesn't. Try out different configurations and see what works in your case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no one right way to do it. Making it 5% smaller every n iterations is totally valid as is dividing it by some factor every so many iterations.